# How can I enable persistent network interface naming with udev on ARM devices running Arch Linux?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, archlinux, udev, beagleboneblack

So I'm running Arch on both a Raspberry Pi and a Beaglebone Black. Recently I noticed that neither device uses persistent udev naming on their network interfaces (i.e. still using eth0, wlan0 .etc).
On the Raspberry Pi, I deleted the file that prevents udev from renaming the interfaces persistently:

```
/etc/udev/rules.d/80-net-name-slot.rules
```

The Beaglebone Black is newer, and didn't even have the file. Deleting it on the Raspberry Pi appears to have had no effect. Both of them are running systemd 208.
Any idea what's going on here? Is persistent naming not supported on low-end ARM devices, or something?
Here is the output of the following command on both devices:

```
udevadm test-builtin net_id /sys/class/net/eth0
```

On the Raspberry Pi:

```
calling: test-builtin
=== trie on-disk ===
tool version:          208
file size:         5866515 bytes
header size             80 bytes
strings            1296323 bytes
nodes              4570112 bytes
load module index
ID_NET_NAME_MAC=enxb827eb2a5c39
ID_OUI_FROM_DATABASE=Raspberry Pi Foundation
unload module index
```

On the Beaglebone Black:

```
calling: test-builtin
=== trie on-disk ===
tool version:          208
file size:         5866515 bytes
header size             80 bytes
strings            1296323 bytes
nodes              4570112 bytes
load module index
ID_NET_NAME_MAC=enx9059af571ea7
ID_OUI_FROM_DATABASE=Texas Instruments
unload module index
```

Interesting enough, it's missing the ID_NET_NAME_PATH, as I get from my desktop:

```
calling: test-builtin
=== trie on-disk ===
tool version:          208
file size:         5882624 bytes
header size             80 bytes
strings            1301408 bytes
nodes              4581136 bytes
load module index
ID_NET_NAME_MAC=enx8c89a5c6f0ce
ID_OUI_FROM_DATABASE=Micro-Star INT'L CO., LTD
ID_NET_NAME_PATH=enp3s0
unload module index
```

Any ideas? I'd like to plug multiple WiFi adapters into one of these, and would prefer consistency.

Answer (score 2):

You could still force names using MAC addresses:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", ATTR{address}=="12:34:56:78:ab:cd", NAME="whatever"
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", ATTR{address}=="ab:cd:12:34:56:78", NAME="somethingelse"
```